# How to create a new pages using classes in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

I have attempted to create a tkinter GUI which can overlap each page `Page 1, Page 2, Page 3`. I am struggling in two places:

Using the class rather than the method so I have commented them out, but what I have tried at is putting the class in brackets within the command i.e. `command=(mainPage)` but this gives the error:

```
builtins.NameError: name 'mainPage' is not defined
```

Second place I am struggling is not being able to overlap each class.

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class testOverlap(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root

        self.topButtons()

        self.pageOne()
        self.pageTwo()
        self.pageThree()

    def topButtons(self):

        self.firstPage = Button(self.root, text="Go to Page 1", background="WHITE", height = 2, width = 16, command= self.pageOne())
        self.firstPage.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.secondPage = Button(self.root, text="Go to Page 2", background="WHITE",height = 2, width = 16, command= self.pageTwo())
        self.secondPage.place(x=121, y=0)

        self.thirdPage = Button(self.root, text="Go to Page 3", background="WHITE",height = 2, width = 17, command= self.pageThree())
        self.thirdPage.place(x=242, y=0)

#class mainPage(Frame):
    def pageOne(self):
        self.Label1 = Label(self.root, text=" First Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Green")
        self.Label1.place(x=0, y=40)

#class middlePage(Frame):
    def pageTwo(self):
        self.Label2 = Label(self.root, text=" Second Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Blue")
        self.Label2.place(x=0, y=40)

#class finalPage(Frame):
    def pageThree(self):
        self.Label3 = Label(self.root, text=" Third Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Red")
        self.Label3.place(x=0, y=40)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Tk")
    root.geometry('370x340')
    app = testOverlap(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: _"Using the class rather than the method so I have commented them out"_ - this makes no sense. If they are commented out, you are _not_ using classes. Is the problem you're solving using classes or not? If not, I recommend removing the commented code because it's very confusing as written.

Comment: I commented them out because if i left it in it would be classed as a non-functional code but i will try re-iterate this in the future.

Comment: The problem is, removing the class _completely_ changes the nature of the code under the class statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a Frame (page) and raising it (bringing it to the top to view it) are 2 completely different operations. To create it you need to use a layout like `grid` on the class instance, and to raise it you need to use the `tkraise` method of the instance. We usually do this by dedicating a class to do nothing but handle all the pages. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

class Controller(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.pageOne = mainPage(self)
        self.pageOne.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.pageTwo = middlePage(self)
        self.pageTwo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.pageThree = finalPage(self)
        self.pageThree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.menu = testOverlap(self)
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.menu.tkraise() # show the testOverlap Frame now

class testOverlap(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.topButtons()

    def topButtons(self):
        self.firstPage = Button(self, text="Go to Page 1", background="WHITE", height = 2, width = 16, command= self.master.pageOne.tkraise)
        self.firstPage.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.secondPage = Button(self, text="Go to Page 2", background="WHITE",height = 2, width = 16, command= self.master.pageTwo.tkraise)
        self.secondPage.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.thirdPage = Button(self, text="Go to Page 3", background="WHITE",height = 2, width = 17, command= self.master.pageThree.tkraise)
        self.thirdPage.grid(row=0, column=2)

class mainPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.Label1 = Label(self, text=" First Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Green")
        self.Label1.grid()

class middlePage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.Label2 = Label(self, text=" Second Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Blue")
        self.Label2.grid()

class finalPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.Label3 = Label(self, text=" Third Page ", height = 20, width = 52, background="Red")
        self.Label3.grid()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Tk")
    root.geometry('370x340')
    app = Controller(root)
    app.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note also I removed your use of `place`. I recommend you stay away from place if you can, use `grid` or `pack` instead. Using place requires specifying the exact size in a lot of other places, and grid or pack can handle that for you.

Comment: when would you suggest i could use place, could i read on these bugs if you have a link? I am new to python, but this was great help i shall study this code now and compare it to my question.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say `place` causes weird bugs. `place` is entirely deterministic and isn't buggy. The only problems it causes are that it requires  you to do a lot more work if you want your UI to be responsive and easy to maintain.

Comment: `place` should only be used when a floating widget is needed that partially covers up other widgets. It requires that the user defines ALL dimensions, so forgetting one makes the whole thing not work (which is what happens if you replace grid with place in the code above) or it makes things appear off screen with new fonts / versions of python / computers. For now forget that place exists and let tkinter do the hard work.

Comment: No, that's not necessarily true that place is only for floating widgets. `place` is actually quite good when you want to stack widgets on top of each other. it has other uses as well. `place` is actually quite powerful and flexible. I don't recommend it for most work, and I especially don't recommend it for beginners, but it's definitely good for more things than just floating widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited out the buggy comment, I agree that implied something wrong with tkinter not the user. But I disagree with your other comment; I have yet to find any other use for place that can't be solved more easily and neater with grid. (Mind floating widgets is a very important role; I'm not advocating for never using place.)

Comment: @Novel: there are other ways it is better than grid, but I guess the comment section isn't the right place to enumerate them. The point is, `pack`, `grid`, and `place` all have their uses, and each is superior to the other in one way or another.

Comment: @Novel I was just curious to understand why the GUI starts at page 3 and not mainPage?

Comment: It should start at testOverlap since that's the last one to be laid out. You can add `self.menu.tkraise()` to the end of the `Controller.__init__` to force it if needed.

Comment: @Novel How do you mean, sorry?